# Android почему кнопки не помещаются на экране

Tags: android

На экране располагаю горизонтально две кнопки.
Размер экрана 1920х1080, запускаю на эмуляторе.

у каждой

```
layuot_width = 140dp
```

у левой левая привязка 40dp, правой нет

у правой правая привязка 40dp, левой нет

и еще у каждой верхняя привязка к верхнему элементу
Я так понимаю они должны выдержать размер 140dp и отступы с права и с лева по 40dp, а в центре уже как получиться. Вместо этого получаю такую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не пойму с чего они растянулись на весь экран?

xml-файл

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EditGeneralTableActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edTextCurName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinEditTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edTextCurName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edTextCurName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTextCurName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveEditTable"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSave"
        android:text="@string/button_save"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinEditTable" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteEditTable"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_delete"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinEditTable" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуй использовать `ConstraintLayout` 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout

Comment: покажите что у вас в разметке то (xml файле)

Comment: По разметке все верно. В чем может быть проблема - посмотрите мб где то в стилях или теме переписываются значения для Button, так же изображение может отличатся на разных диагоналях устройств, если на 5 дюймах все отлично то уже на 4.7 и 4.0 кнопки будут двигаться все ближе

Comment: Выглядит вполне нормально. Стандартная ширина экрана - `360dp` - вы как раз в неё вписались - `140+140+40+40 = 360`